# r highcharter package barplot group vs. color

Tags: r, highcharts

I have a tidy dataframe, similar to the following:

```
tidyDF <- data.frame(PORT_NAME = c("South Louisiana, LA, Port of",
                               "Houston, TX", "Long Beach, CA",
                               "New York, NY and NJ",
                               "Los Angeles, CA", "Beaumont, TX",
                               "Corpus Christi, TX", "New Orleans, LA",
                               "Baton Rouge, LA", "Mobile, AL"),
                 TOTAL_TONS = c(267390209, 234304391, 170052128, 
                                126158655, 122033848, 87283716, 84928330,
                                84465052, 69185878, 64287565),
                 portSel = c("NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES",
                             "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO"))
```

I would like to create a barplot with specific colors based on the `portSel` variable.

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(highcharter)
myColors <- c("#002F80", "#F9AF38")

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series_df(data = tidyDF,
                   type = "bar",
                   x = PORT_NAME,
                   y = TOTAL_TONS,
                   group = portSel) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Ports"),
           tickmarkPlacement = "on",
           tickLength = 0,
           labels = list(
             enabled = FALSE
           )) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "2014 Total Tonnage")) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_colors(myColors)
```

I have tried both `group` and `color` in `hc_add_series_df`.  Neither work correctly. When I use `group = portSel`, as above, the colors are correct, but it moves the single YES port to be grouped with the first NO port.  When I use `color = portSel`, it puts the YES port in the correct spot, but it no longer uses the custom colors in `myColors`.

Any advice is welcome!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the previous answer.

You're not using groups in the right way. The `group` option is to create/add more than 1 series, that's why the first `yes` is next to the first `no` because the value are put in order.

About the colors, the function `hc_add_series_df` colorize the points (bars, column) according the given color variable so don't use the color given by `hc_colors`.

So, I think a simple way to do this is add the series "manually". This means craete a list from the data with the specific data (and color) that you want.

```
tidyDF2 <- tidyDF %>% 
  mutate(color = ifelse(portSel == "NO", myColors[1], myColors[2])) %>% 
  select(y = TOTAL_TONS, color)


highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(labels = list(
    enabled = FALSE
    )) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = list_parse(tidyDF2), showInLegend = FALSE)
```

Does this help you?

---

Previous answer.

You can try add in `hc_xAxis` the next arguments: `type = "categorical", categories = tidyDF$PORT_NAME,` and use just group in `hc_add_series_df`. You will see a bar chart with the "yes" column a little displace due you put 2 series (one for each group), for example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series_df(data = tidyDF,
                   type = "bar",
                   x = PORT_NAME,
                   y = TOTAL_TONS,
                   group = portSel) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Ports"),
           type = "categorical",
           categories = tidyDF$PORT_NAME,
           tickmarkPlacement = "on",
           tickLength = 0,
           labels = list(
             enabled = TRUE
           )) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "2014 Total Tonnage")) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_colors(myColors)
```

Comment: This did not work.  The categories don't line up. Beaumont is at the top aligned with Southern Louisiana.  Is there a reason that we can not control the colors if we use the `color = portSel` instead of `group`. `color` keeps the bars lined up correctly, but I lose the ability to control the specific colors.  I tried both `hc_colors`, and adding colors to a theme through `hc_theme`. Seems strange.